# Grouping same values from a single column while retaining the data in

Tags: r

[image]

This is my current code for this image data[1:20,c("Job.Family", "Salaries", "Retirement")]. The goal here is to group all the same jobs in the Job.Family column together without loosing any data associated with it. So for example I would like to find out the sum of "Salaries" and "Retirement" for all those in the "Information System" Job.Family. Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: don't attach your data by images, please read this to make people here understand and fix your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking into some very basic subsetting and summarising operations here.
I strongly recommend you study the `dplyr` package.
Your example:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% filter(Job.Family = "Information Systems") %>% 
       summarise(across(c(Salaries, Retirement), mean))
```

You may want to calculate this for all groups, as in:

```
df %>% group_by(Job.Family) %>% 
       summarise(across(c(Salaries, Retirement), mean))
```